# Possible iOS13 or Xcode bug with new ViewController Presentation Style

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I'm having an issue with the margin of a right `NavigationBarButton`.

I've distilled this down to a fresh single-view project in Xcode 11. I have a launch screen storyboard and a main storyboard.

The main storyboard has an `Initial ViewController` with a single button that points to a `NavigationController` and a resulting `ViewController`.

The toolbar has two buttons that appear as such:

[image]

If I then segue to another `NavigationController` with a `ViewController` with two bar buttons, it looks like this:

[image]

Why, in the second `ViewController`, is the right button against the edge and not the margin?

UPDATE: This appears to be a problem with the new presentation style in iOS 13. If I change the first navigation controller presentation style to fullscreen, the second controller now displays properly (the Item button is properly aligned to the margin).

Might this be a bug in iOS or Xcode?

Comment: What do your constraints look like? Do you have any relevant code?

Comment: I didn't create any constraints (I didn't;t think you could do that on a button bar item).  I also didn't need to write any code to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: If anyone wants to try the project it is at https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArrsM4oXrGGbp6J0p4_-YFr6ogXYeA?e=KhkZPL

Answer (score 0):

## Yes, it's a bug in iOS 13

The solution is to force a layout, [as explained on the Apple forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121861) by user DaleOne:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewWillAppear(animated)
     if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
          navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you translate that into objective C for me please?

Comment: I don't know Objective-C, besides Swift has been around for a while now...

Comment: I solved the problem in a different way having discovered it's not a bug but a consequence of a change in interface style and managed to hack some objC together from a different swift workaround. Thanks anyway.